# Is it possible to show a Google Gauge chart for only one column in a DataTable

Tags: google-visualization

I want to some data in a Google Chart dashboard that has a column chart and a gauge chart from  the same data set.  I would like to show all the data from the data in the column chart but only one in the gauge chart.  For example if my data looked like:

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Service', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
      ['All', 7,  9,  23],
      ['Breakdown1', 7,  9,  23],
      ['Breakdown2', 0,  0,  0]
    ]);
```

I would like to be able to pass that data to the Chart dashboard and only show 1 gauge per line (using the 'X' column).  As it stands the code I have creates a gauge for each entry

```
        var gaugeChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Gauge',
        'containerId': 'chart1',
        'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 180,
            'majorTicks': ["","", "", "", "", ""]
        }
    });
```

When I want to show only one gauge (not three).  Is there an option to pass to the Gauge Chart the specific column to display with the Gauge and not to display all columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select which columns to use in a [Chart Wrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject) Class you can set the 
 view option.  Therefore

```
var gaugeChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Gauge',
    'containerId': 'chart1',
    'options': {
        'width': 300,
        'height': 180,
        'majorTicks': ["","", "", "", "", ""]
    },
    'view': {'columns': [0, 1]}
});
```

gives the functionality that I required